# Are these two asymptotic notations equal?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, logarithms, asymptotics, computer-science

I see two notations and try to understand these are the same or not? (from two views)

$O( n * (log m) * (log n))$ is equal to $O( n * (log m + log n))$ from logarithm property and from asymptotic order?

Comment: No: the logarithm property says that $\log m+\log n = \log(mn)$, not $(\log m)(\log n)$. The function $n(\log m)(\log n)$ is not $O(n(\log m+\log n)$ (unless either $m$ or $n$ is bounded).

Comment: Yes ... although in a way that has nothing to do with $O$ notation—it's just how logarithms work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No: the logarithm property says that $\log m+\log n=\log(mn)$, not $(\log m)(\log n)$. The function $n(\log m)(\log n)$ is not $O(n(\log m+\log n))$ (unless either $m$ or $n$ is bounded).

So $O(k(\log n+\log k)) = O(k\log(nk))$, although that statement has nothing to do with the $O$ notation, but is simply a fact about logarithm functions.